# Redis database file (dump.rdb) does not shrink after deleting 95% of keys

Tags: redis

All deleted more than 95% of may keys using **DEL** command.
The database dump file after save and bgsave is still the same as before delete.
I also noticed the memory (used_memory_human:160.96M) is still as high save before. I have only 7669 keys left.

Keyspace

db1:keys=**7669**,expires=145,avg_ttl=13314857

How to compact the memory and database after deleting the keys?

Answer (score 2):

The size of the RDB and `used_memory` are the actual amount of data you have in Redis. That means that the remaining 7669 keys take up this space - whether it is just one big key hiding among them, a few large ones or maybe all keys are about 0.05MB each.

Comment: I am suspected on this b/c the memory and db size does not change before and after delete. Keys/Values are the same object for all records. 


**Before Delete** 

#Memory used_memory:168782256
used_memory_human:**160.96M** 
# Keyspace db1:keys=**49487**,expires=0,avg_ttl=0 

### After Delete ### 

db1:keys=7669,expires=145,avg_ttl=13314857

Comment: What happens when you load the RDB back?

Comment: When I load the RDB back, it shows the I have 7669 keys but the memory size and db save does not shrink before or after that. When I run **SAVE** or **BGSAVE** the RDB dump size is almost same size of the original db before delete.

Comment: I've developed my delete problem in Golang

Comment: run `redis-cli --big-keys` or [redis-rdb-tools](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) to understand what's in your DB - the Go code in the gist is nice and all (although you're using the **evil** `KEYS` command - beware!) but it doesn't say anything about the keys that remain in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to find which keys are taking the most memory in your database.

This command may help you

`redis-cli -h hostname -p portnumber --bigkeys`

or `redis-cli --bigkeys` if you are using the default host and port number.

It will go through the DB and report the largest keys that it finds. It can be time consuming for large DBs with many keys but 8k keys it should run very quickly.